# "down vote favorite" appearing in many posts

Tags: discussion

There are surprisingly many results for ["down vote favorite" on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22down+vote+favorite%22).  This seems to be proceeded by the post score, but not always, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550340/menu-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-menu) is at -3 but starts with "0 down vote favorite".

Why is this text being inserted in posts?

If it's user error, is there something we can do to prevent it?  For example, as it's usually at the beginning of the post, can we trim it out like we do for "Hi" etc.?

Comment: It's picked up if you try to select and copy text from a question, but accidentally select back across the favorite star and the downvote button as well (and the number'll be present if you go as far back as the vote total). Not sure why those icons are being converted to text, or why so many people are pasting copied text from a question into their question.

Comment: well, those two buttons do have text within them to be copied.

Comment: @sph cuz of alt text of buttons, of curs.

Comment: Trimming it out would be actively harmful. These are blatant indicators that the content was copy-pasted from somewhere on Stack Exchange, and that **it should be deleted**.

Comment: @animuson The question I linked does not appear to have been copied from anywhere according to SO search (at least for a non-10Ker).

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That one was [copy-pasted from Android Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98990/menu-xmlnsandroid-http-schemas-android-com-apk-res-android-menu-appear)

Comment: @animuson [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347860/display-records-page-wise-using-asp-net-without-using-gridview-in-asp-net), but guess they probably copied it from their own deleted questions or something like that?

Comment: If you lose the 'favorite', you get copy-pasted answers (which do not have the favorite star): [0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%220+down+vote%22), [1](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%221+down+vote%22), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%222+down+vote%22), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%223+down+vote%22), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%224+down+vote%22), [11](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2211+down+vote%22). You could add 'accpeted', which is inserted when copying accepted answers like this.

Comment: Uber Meta duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178365/what-is-0-down-vote-favorite

Comment: It's funny people clain their posts should be downvote favorites :)

Comment: @animuson Is it bad form to [put the same content](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17791115/241211) on >1 SE site? I thought that was okay.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Those words are the alt-text for the Downvote and Favorite icons. If you go to select the text from a question but you accidentally select back across the favorite star and the downvote button as well, you'll get those words in your copied text, and selecting back to the vote total will include the number. That said, I don't know what workflow so many people are going through that's causing them to accidentally copy that from some question and then paste it into their own questions, but that'd be where it's coming from. As mentioned in the comments, the presence of such garbage text is a potentially useful indicator that the content following was copied from an existing question elsewhere on the SE network.

Comment: The workflow is usually one of "my question didn't get answered, I'm going to copy-paste it into a new question" or "this also applies to another site, I'll copy-paste it there."

Comment: "And then I won't bother to read what comes out."

Comment: Should those questions be closed as low quality or duplicates even if the source is unknown? (although I bet that a quick search online would return something)

Comment: Well you can't close a question as a duplicate unless you have a link that it's a duplicate of.

Comment: All of the "down vote favorite" questions are gone.  It looks like someone decided to nuke them all.  Hopefully all were either crap questions on the merits, or the nuker confirmed that the original version was still around.

Comment: Why would one want to copy the *rendered* text of the question, losing all formatting, and then re-apply all the formatting manually, instead of copying the source code? The only reason I can think of is that people are not copying their own un-answered questions, but rather copying another user's question and lacking the reputation to open the editor.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Or they didn't realize that they could get the formatting by editing the post.  Given that these people aren't actually checking the output at any level, I think it's safe to assume that that's possible.

Comment: @DanNeely Some of them were also just edited to remove the text. Most of them were duplicates, though, and got deleted.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Another possibility: The people copying and pasting questions are probably new to the site (or they wouldn't be doing it in the first place) and so the idea to copy from source may not be obvious to them.